Copy User Defined Fields from Sales Order Line to Purchase Order Line on Clicking 'Create Purchase Order' Action in Sales Order Screen (SO301000)
I have a few user defined fields in sales order line which I need to copy when the 'Create Purchase Order' action is clicked in the sales order screen. I was able to get the copying of the user defined fields from SOLine to POLine but there is a small issue, if the SO line item inventory IDs are the same but they have different values for soLineExt.UsrCustomPackageType then the purchase order created should have separate lines for them , as of now it does not do this but only creates the purchase order with one line.
Eg: this is a sales order with same inventory ID for the sales order lines but with different package type
Sales Order Line with Same Inventory ID and Different Package Type
Create Purchase Order with 3 Lines
Created PO with only one Line
I have tried this override action based on the source code
using PX.Objects.PO;

namespace PX.Objects.PO
{
  public class POCreate_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.PO.POCreate>
  {
   public delegate POLine FindOrCreatePOLineDelegate(POOrderEntry docgraph, DocumentList<POLine> ordered, String orderType, POFixedDemand demand, SOLineSplit3 soline);
[PXOverride]
public POLine FindOrCreatePOLine(
    POOrderEntry docgraph,
    DocumentList<POLine> ordered,
    String orderType,
    POFixedDemand demand,
    SOLineSplit3 soline,
    FindOrCreatePOLineDelegate baseMethod)
{
    PXTrace.WriteInformation($"FindOrCreatePOLine called for SOLine: OrderType={soline.OrderType}, OrderNbr={soline.OrderNbr}, LineNbr={soline.LineNbr}");

    // Call the base method to get or create the POLine
    POLine poLine = baseMethod(docgraph, ordered, orderType, demand, soline);

    if (poLine != null && soline != null)
    {
        // Fetch the associated SOLine using its line reference
        SOLine soLine = PXSelect<SOLine,
                         Where<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>,
                            And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>,
                            And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.lineNbr>>>>>>
                         .Select(docgraph, soline.OrderType, soline.OrderNbr, soline.LineNbr);

        if (soLine != null)
        {
            // Retrieve the extensions
            var soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(soLine);
            var poLineExt = PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(poLine);

            if (soLineExt != null && poLineExt != null)
            {
                PXTrace.WriteInformation($"SOLine CustomPackageType: {soLineExt.UsrCustomPackageType}");

                // Check if the POLine is being created for the first time
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(poLineExt.UsrPackageType))
                {
                    PXTrace.WriteInformation("POLine is being created for the first time, setting CustomPackageType.");
                    // Ensure this POLine gets its own line for this PackageType
                    poLineExt.UsrPackageType = soLineExt.UsrCustomPackageType;
                    poLineExt.UsrPackageQty = soLineExt.UsrPackageQty;
                    poLineExt.UsrDeliveryNotes = soLineExt.UsrDeliveryNotes;
                    poLineExt.UsrDeliveryNoteDetail = soLineExt.UsrDeliveryNoteDetail;
                    poLineExt.UsrCountryOfOrigin = soLineExt.UsrCountryOfOrigin;
                    poLineExt.UsrCropYear = soLineExt.UsrCropYear;
                    poLineExt.UsrBrand = soLineExt.UsrBrand;
                }
                else
                {
                    PXTrace.WriteInformation($"POLine CustomPackageType: {poLineExt.UsrPackageType}");

                    // Check if a POLine with the same InventoryID but a different CustomPackageType exists
                    PXSelectBase<POLine> query = new PXSelect<POLine,
                                                 Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POLine.orderNbr>>,
                                                     And<POLine.inventoryID, Equal<Required<POLine.inventoryID>>,
                                                     And<POLineExt.usrPackageType, NotEqual<Required<POLineExt.usrPackageType>>>>>>(docgraph);
                    POLine existingPOLine = query.Select(poLine.OrderNbr, poLine.InventoryID, soLineExt.UsrCustomPackageType);

                    if (existingPOLine == null)
                    {
                        PXTrace.WriteInformation("No existing POLine found with different CustomPackageType, updating current POLine.");
                        // Ensure this POLine gets its own line for this PackageType
                        poLineExt.UsrPackageType = soLineExt.UsrCustomPackageType;
                        poLineExt.UsrPackageQty = soLineExt.UsrPackageQty;
                        poLineExt.UsrDeliveryNotes = soLineExt.UsrDeliveryNotes;
                        poLineExt.UsrDeliveryNoteDetail = soLineExt.UsrDeliveryNoteDetail;
                        poLineExt.UsrCountryOfOrigin = soLineExt.UsrCountryOfOrigin;
                        poLineExt.UsrCropYear = soLineExt.UsrCropYear;
                        poLineExt.UsrBrand = soLineExt.UsrBrand;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PXTrace.WriteInformation("Existing POLine found with different CustomPackageType, creating a new POLine.");
                        // If a line with the same InventoryID and a different CustomPackageType exists, create a new POLine
                        POLine newPOLine = PXCache<POLine>.CreateCopy(poLine);
                        poLineExt = PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(newPOLine);
                        poLineExt.UsrPackageType = soLineExt.UsrCustomPackageType;
                        poLineExt.UsrPackageQty = soLineExt.UsrPackageQty;
                        poLineExt.UsrDeliveryNotes = soLineExt.UsrDeliveryNotes;
                        poLineExt.UsrDeliveryNoteDetail = soLineExt.UsrDeliveryNoteDetail;
                        poLineExt.UsrCountryOfOrigin = soLineExt.UsrCountryOfOrigin;
                        poLineExt.UsrCropYear = soLineExt.UsrCropYear;
                        poLineExt.UsrBrand = soLineExt.UsrBrand;
                        return newPOLine;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return poLine;
}

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!
